# Which DSpace Docker container is officially endorsed by the DSpace community?

Tags: docker, dspace

The Docker hub contains a number of DSpace Docker containers:

https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=DSpace&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&pullCount=0&starCount=0

I personally only have experience with
https://hub.docker.com/r/quantumobject/docker-dspace/

Likes

- Create administrator is according to the instructions the only command line action that needs to happen after deployment
- It runs DSpace 5.3, the latest official stable release of DSpace
- runs Java 7 instead of Java 8 (which is not fully tested with DSpace yet)

Dislikes

- There's an issue with postgres, reported as closed on https://github.com/QuantumObject/docker-dspace/issues/2 but I still encountered it
- It can't run on a 1GB AWS instance, because it deploys both the XMLUI as well as the JSPUI
- It runs Tomcat 8 instead of Tomcat 7
- It seems to be on Ubuntu 15 instead of Ubuntu 14 LTS (probably more of a personal preference)

Don't get me wrong - I love the work done by this contributor, but I was wondering if there is a reference implementation out there, or if this one could serve as a reference implementation.

Comment: Hi Bram, currently we don't have an "endorsed" DSpace Docker container. I'd welcome us creating one under the DSpace GitHub project (https://github.com/DSpace/), similar to how we already have an "endorsed" Vagrant project there (https://github.com/DSpace/vagrant-dspace).

So, if you or anyone else is interested in beginning such a project, I'd welcome it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository https://github.com/DSpace-Labs/DSpace-Docker-Images details the DSpace docker images created and supported by the project.

Each supported branch of DSpace now has one or more Dockerfiles for each branch.